# Loop in C runs unexpectedly

Tags: c, loops

In chapter 6 exercise 8 in N King
[C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0393979504/) (2008), the following code is given. In my testing, the output shows infinite loop behaviour with value 1, whereas I think the correct output should be 10 5 3 1.

I changed the variable type to float but still doesn't work; tried a while loop but still the wrong output. Also tried other different things but still the same error.

```
for (int i=10; i>=1; i/=2)
    printf("%d ",i++);
system("pause");
```

expected output: `10 5 3 2 1`
actual result: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` in the `printf` call?

Comment: actual result is `10 5 3 2 1 1 1 1 1...`

Comment: Why do you have `i++` in `printf`? Remove the `++`.

Comment: thanks for the help guys i understood it. and as for the people asking why i put i++ in printf. it's what's written in the book.

Comment: BTW, the question in the book (yes, I found it) is asking *what* output will the code have. It doesn't tell you that it is `10, 5, 3..` that is expected. So now you know that it will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: yes eugene i was not able to understand how it turned into an infinte loop. but now i understand so thanks for the hep. :)

Comment: `3/2=1; +1=2; /2=1; +1=2; /2=1; ...` scenery never changes...

Comment: I suspect you're missing the 10, 5, 3, at the start before the blizzard of 1's.  Pipe the output to (`more` or) `less` or equivalent.

Comment: or pipe the result to `head`

Answer (score 3):

Let us check the output every loop. The post increment and the print are seperated for clarity.

Loop iteration 1:

- `i` is initialized to 10
- print `i` --> print 10
- `i++   --> i==11`
- `i >=1 --> TRUE`
- `i/=2  --> i==5`

Loop iteration 2:

- print `i` --> print 5
- `i++   --> i==6`
- `i >=1 --> TRUE`
- `i/=2  --> i==3`

Loop iteration 3:

- print `i` --> print 3
- `i++   --> i==4`
- `i >=1 --> TRUE`
- `i/=2  --> i==2`

Loop iteration 4:

- print `i` --> print 2
- `i++   --> i==3`
- `i >=1 --> TRUE`
- `i/=2  --> i==1`

Loop iteration 5:

- print `i` --> print 1
- `i++   --> i==2`
- `i >=1 --> TRUE`
- `i/=2  --> i==1`

As you can see at this stage, we get the value `i==1` again. So this loop is repeated for ever.

As mentioned by @Jonathan above, you are probably missing the first few values in the continuous stream of `1`s later.